# Error deploying new contract in Javascript using Meteor and TemplateVar

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, remix, javascript, meteor

I am trying to create a new contract on button click using Meteor and TemplateVar. The relevant code is:

```
Template.Borrower.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // Create new Borrower
    var _borrower = "ABC"

    alert("I am working on it...")

    web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0x...");

    var newBorrower = web3.eth.contract(borrowerABIArray).new(_borrower,{from:eth.accounts[0],data:borrowerData,gas:500000}, function(err, newContract){
    if(!err) {

      if(!newContract.address) {
        alert("Contract transaction sent: TransactionHash: " + newContract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

      } else {
        alert("Contract mined! Address: " + newContract.address);
      }

    }
});
```

I don't even get an error, it just displays the first message "I am working on it..." and then nothing. I am logged into Metamask so my wallet is unlocked but I did try unlocking it as well and that did not work either.

When I deploy the contract directly with Remix it takes less than 300000 gas so it can't be a gas problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I first needed to define newBorrower as a new instance of the contract:

`newBorrower = new web3.eth.contract(borrowerABIArray)`

Then the code works and mines a new Borrower.